# How to use Form classes in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, class, symfony, formbuilder

I am following [the tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) from Symfony2 on how to use form classes.

I am doing something wrong, because when I use the following example code:

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

// add this new use statement at the top of the class
use Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type\TaskType;

public function newAction()
{
    //$task = // ... ???
    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

// ...
}
```

...I receive the following error:

### Notice: Undefined variable: task

I understand that $task has not yet been defined properly. Can anyone explain to me how I should define it? I tried creating it as entity, as formType, as undefined variable, but all to no luck.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the tutorial from the first then you should have created a `Task` entity in `Acme\TaskBundle\Entity` namespace. So your controller would be,

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

// add this new use statement at the top of the class
use Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type\TaskType;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task;

public function newAction()
{
    $task = new Task();
    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

// ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks m2mdas. I did follow the manual as you mention, but only included the part of the manual where I went wrong.

The mistake however, was in the taskType class. In my case, it included the following line:

    $builder->add('Task');

That did not make much sense. (It would have if the entity Task also included a property called Task, but that was not the case.)

Now it works.

Thank you for your quick reply!